# undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass for for array of images delayed job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, delayed-job

Hi i am sending multiple images from paperclip in form of array and then process each image through delayed job,
mode view code is like this

```
<%= f.label :slider_image,'Slider Image' %>
     <%= f.file_field :slider_image, :multiple => true, :accept => "image/*", required: true %>
```

and in controller i am permitted it as array

```
def slider_image_params
  params.require(:slider_image).permit({:slider_image=>[]})
end
def create
  slider_image_params[:slider_image].each do |img|        Spree::SliderImage.delay.create_slider_images(@selected_template,img)
 end
end
```

whenever i putt delay before create_slider_images i get error
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
my paramtes are like this

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"7d9yFPVvfTiywcX6YRMxqtk/gg4Y+T2pS0W8TcJ0L2w=",
 "slider_image"=>{"slider_image"=>[#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000009e41e58 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20150821-8626-13ll574>,
 @original_filename="sliderbg.jpg",
 @content_type="image/jpeg",
 @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"slider_image[slider_image][]\"; filename=\"sliderbg.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">]}}
```

without delay it is working fine can anybody please explain. i think it is issue as i am permitting attributes in form of array.

Comment: It is very difficult to help you since you haven't posted the full stacktrace of what line of code you are seeing "undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass" on. Please post the FULL stacktrace (include Rails + Gem lines too) where you see the exception.

Comment: Also you haven't specified what job queue you are using (Resque, Sidekiq, etc)

Comment: And also you haven't specified the delay mechanism. Who defines 'delay' ?

Answer (score 1):

In an ephemeral architecture (Heroku) your app design won't work at all. Heck, if you even just have 2 servers your design won't work at all.  That might not be relevant if you just have 1 server.

If I were trying to do multiple file upload I would definitely use a direct S3 upload technique, not what you have done here (see https://github.com/waynehoover/s3_direct_upload)

Finally, assuming you are using resque-delayed for your 'delay' method, you can't really pass objects directly into resque. You should save the object to the database and then pass only the object id to resque, so that the job can re-load it and the create_slider_images can re-load the object using the id.